# Appcelerator Windows Phone Push Notifications

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-arrow

Does Appcelerator currently have the functionality to register for Windows Phone Push notifications?
I cant seem to find any information in the documentation, or find any modules for this capability. Can only find information specifically for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Titanium Windows SDK nor Appcelerator Arrow Push supports Windows at the moment.

The next Titanium 5.3 release will be all about Windows so you can expect it to be in place next quarter.

Comment: Titanium 5.3 beta is out now. I went through the documentation - http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_5.3.0.Beta_Release_Note. No mention of push notifications on windows phone yet. Can you please suggest when we can expect it in beta?

Comment: I see this has been resolved for 5.4 (June): https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20578

Comment: ok thanks, that will be great! I have one question though, is it possible to configure push notifications on Windows phone using Microsoft Azure Notifications Hub in appcelerator? I found this - https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/11522?restoreSearch=true#!overview, but can't find a good documentation to configure it for Windows phones.

Comment: This module is Android+iOS only but we should add Windows support indeed. I've created an internal ticket to do this. Please see the discussion on the [PR](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_windows/pull/635) for more details on the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! One final clarification, is there any third party push notification service or module I can use with appcelerator builds on Windows platform to get my hands dirty until it is launched in appcelerator?

Comment: Not that I know off.